# Попадание точки в зону

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Столкнулся с задачей когда есть зоны доставок и пользователь вводит адрес, и уже по заданному адресу определяется стоимость доставки. Сам код написал и он хорошо работает в калькулятор стоимости доставок, а вот на странице оформления уже не хочет определять попадание в зону. Я так понимаю что это из-за того что нужно обязательно отображать карту, а есть ли еще какой-то способ? Плюс если карту скрывать стилями - не работает и карта должна быть нормальных размеров и с нормальным zoomом, иначе тоже не все области проверяет, как я понял.

Answer (score 0):

Если для калькулятора используются методы JS API Карт, то ряд из них действительно требует фактической отрисовки объектов на карте.

Если вопрос стоит в экономии трафика, то API для скрипта вы всё равно загружаете, экономии тут не выйдет.

Кроме того, использование API Яндекс.Карт без отображения карты нарушает [пользовательское соглашение](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) для бесплатных ключей.